# Вычисление (Pow(a,b) mod c) при больших a,b,c

Tags: c#

Как вычислить данное выражение не словив переполнение при `Pow` ?

```
ulong Pow(ulong a, ulong b)
{
  ulong p = 1;
  for (ulong i = 0; i < b; ++i)
    p *= a;
  return p;
}

ulong m = Pow(a, b) % c;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если `a * c` не вылезает за `ulong`, то так:

```
ulong Pow(ulong a, ulong b)
{
  a = a % c;
  ulong p = 1;
  for (ulong i = 0; i < b; ++i)
    p = (p * a) % c;
  return p;
}
```

Инвариант: `p < c`. При умножении `p * a < c * a`, и по условию переполнения не происходит.

---

Обновление: для больших значений степени имеет смысл умножать путём последовательного возведения в квадрат.

```
ulong Pow(ulong a, ulong b)
{
  a = a % c;
  ulong p = 1;
  ulong r = 1;
  while (b > 0)
  {
    if (b % 2 != 0)
      r = (r * p) % c;
    b = b / 2;
    p = (p * a) % c;
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: а как избежать "долгого" исполнения кода при больших "b"

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик: Можно оптимизировать умножение, возводить много раз в квадрат. А ещё возможно покатит малая теорема Ферма.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик: Добавил код с последовательным возведением в квадрат (не тестировал).

Comment: я уточню, если `с` большое и `a*c` вылазит за `ulong` то можно умножение заменить на сложение и воспользоваться такой же идеей как и в быстром умножении.

Comment: @pavel: Классная идея, кстати.

Comment: Можно ещё по идее разделить `a` и `c` на 32-битные части, и перемножать как в столбик, по кускам.

Comment: @VladD перемножить так можно, а вот остаток взять уже не тривиально. Это по сложности реализации уже к длинной арифметике ближе.

Comment: @pavel: ну, надо отдельно посчитать `q = 2^32 mod c`, и получится `x * y mod c = (x_lo * y_lo mod c + x_lo * y_hi * q mod c + x_hi * y_lo * q mod c + x_hi * y_lo * q * q mod c) mod c`. Причём для тройных-четверных умножений понадобится наверное приводить к модулю после каждого сомножителя.

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм Монтгомери позволяет это делать https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8